# How to resize design 4500*5400 px in Illustrator CS6?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need to resize my shirt design 4500x5400 but I can't. When I set the size 4500*5400 px in Illustrator and save as png it show beyond my size. I'm really worried please anyone is here to help me how to exact resize and will show  4500*5400 png after save the image?

Comment: How did you "set the size" in illustrator? Are you referring to the size of the content on the Artboard? Or is that the size of the Artboard?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome, Saba.

The Adobe Illustrator will only honor your dimensions in pixels if you export the design to 72ppi.

But exporting it in 300ppi, the design will be resampled to honor the dimension in the real world. Eg: cm, mm, inches...
Placing it back to Illustrator, the design comes with the same dimensions you exported but showing its respective depth in pixels.

There are a lot of explanations about this. Just google it. Or see the @Danielillo 's comment.

I show below two exported designs showing the results for comparison:

**Image in Finder:**
[image]

**Image in Illustrator:**

[image]